# cannot run only one app in ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm unable to run only one app in my iphone 6s. it gives follwing error

[image]

I tried so many things like

- delete the app manually from the device and reinstall
- switch off the iphone and run
- close the xcode nd run
- by changing the bundle identifier
- changing the team (devloper account)
- restart the mac and tried with xcode.

nothing works

> **app runs in the simulator nicely and also, I tried to run another app in my iphone 6s device. it was success. I have no idea what is going on. hope your help with this.**

NOTE :Same happened three days ago, then I updated my xcode and the ios version on my phone. then it worked. but now it act as the same way.

Comment: Can you please the provisioning profile which you are using does containt the device id in it. Are you using development or distribution profile?

Comment: @bill: Which Xcode version you are using? What is the deployment version? What is the iPhone 6's ios version?

Comment: xcode 8.2.1 the latest

Comment: check your device version in xcode package : Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer

Comment: @bill : And the deployment version of the project? iPhone 6's ios version?

Comment: deployment target of the project is 9.0 and my phone has the latest os 10.2 @ Poles

Comment: @Miteshjadav how to check it

Comment: @Hrishikesh I tried with both development and distribution

Comment: @bill Go to finder  : Application -> Right click on xcode -> Select content package ... next path is already give

Comment: @bill: Select no team and try to run project in your device. Check this

Comment: @Hrishikesh you mean to team = none, then it ask for developer team

Comment: @Miteshjadav I navigatet to Developer and there are two directories Library and SDKs

Comment: @bill.Have u tried removing derived data

Comment: @bill: Yes. team = none and try to build and run your project.

Comment: @Hrishikesh it gives me two errors. one is that ask for development team and other for `Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'`

Comment: In Xcode 8 you can't select team as none unless you change provision profile

Comment: @bill: In Xcode 8.2 check Automatically manage signing and try it. See what happen now. Target - > General -> Automatically manage signing

Comment: /iPhoneSimulator.platform/ - > Device support  - > 10.2

Comment: @Hrishikesh I have already checked it

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

- go to your accounts in xcode preferences.
- select your account and tap view details
- delete (move to trash by right clicking) all provisioning profiles.
- download all again.

this will solve the problem.
thanx everyone who supported me.